# QGIS 2.0, SpatiaLite: labels disappear after setting data defined position (x,y)

Tags: qgis, labeling, spatialite

I added to my SpatiaLite table (.osm-import with the "standard" QGIS-OSM-Plugin) two empty columns x and y (double) to define manually the position of my labels (data defined labeling). But after telling the layer about the x and y-column, all labels just disapears!

I tested it in different CRS and with different data types and lengths. I created the columns in QGIS (When I create them in DB-Manager or Qspatialite, they wont appear in the QGIS attribute table)

Im absolutely new to SQL databases!

Thats my table:
[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

Creating a column with

```
ALTER TABLE "pelepo_300114_place" ADD COLUMN label_x integer
```

works but is NOT displayed in Qgis. (I tryed it with integer, numeric, float...)

Comment: I would like to change the question, because the main problem is not the labeling (as we fould out now). Its the fact that my new columns are just not displayed in qgis.

Answer (score 3):

You say you are defining two empty columns X and Y of type double, but on the screenshots they appear as integers. Also, there is no double type as numeric on sqlite:

- http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html
- http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Which version os spatialite are you using?

Can you add the columns with an [sql command](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) with the [shell](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html)?

Comment: SQLite version: 3.7.9; SpatiaLite Library: 4.1.0; I created the columns with [ALTER TABLE "pelepo_300114_place" 
ADD COLUMN label_x integer]

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly related to this bug: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9148

Basically, in database tables, you can't use a null value for default coordinates when using doubles (or equivalent). Look into the issue tracker to find out why.

My workaround is to use string for those X and Y label coordinates. QGIS handles null/empty strings as you expect, meaning that default values don't need to be manually entered.

Comment: Thank you but thats not the problem. I tryed it with strings also.